# Attribute Error in finding element python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
    top_gainers_div = soup.find("div", id="24_hours_movers").find("div", class_="col-md-6")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I cannot scrape the Top Gainers within Market Movers on https://www.futbin.com/market/ - but i keep getting an attribute error and cannot seem to find the correct class

The code is below, what Ive tried is to find the top movers

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.futbin.com/market/"
WEBHOOK_URLS = [
    "x",
    "x"
]

# Make an HTTP GET request to the website
response = requests.get(URL)

# Parse the HTML content of the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

# Find the div containing the top gainers
top_gainers_div = soup.find("div", id="24_hours_movers").find("div", class_="col-md-6")

# Find the div containing the small card holders
card_holder_divs = top_gainers_div.find_all("div", class_="d-inline")

# Find all the small card holders in the div
card_holders = card_holders_div.find_all("div", class_="d-inline mx-2")
```

here is the site source concerning the top gainers, as you can see the elements are there.

```
 <div class="row col-12 m_box m_box_g pb-0">


            <div class="row pl-4 pt-2">
                <h6 class="font-weight-500 pl-2">All Market Movers </h6>
            </div>

            <div class="row col-md-12  pl-4">
                <ul class="nav  md-pills  p-2">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#24_hours_movers" data-toggle="tab">
                           24 Hours
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#4_hours_movers" data-toggle="tab">
                            4 Hours
                        </a>
                    </li>


                </ul>
            </div>


            <div class="row all-market-movers tab-content pt-3 mt-1">

                    <div id="24_hours_movers" class="row text-center tab-pane active">

                        <div class=" col-md-6">
                            <div class="row col-12 pl-3">
                                <h6 class="font-weight-bold">Top Gainers</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                                                    <div class="d-inline mx-2">
                                        <a class="small-card-holder  get-tp" target="" href="/23/player/26787/de-tomas"
                                                data-year="23"
                                              data-site-id="26787"
                                              data-tp-type="player"
```

Comment: Can you please include your code in a single chunk? That way we can see which libraries you have imported, which variables you have declared, and how you've organised it all? No need to include everything, just a minimal reproducible example. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Done, added the snippet of code concerned with the error

Comment: It looks like the first `find` call came back empty-handed, but you ploughed on anyway, and hit a `None`. You'll have to check the first `<div>` exists before proceeding. This is a common problem when chaining, you *must* be sure the intermediate call can't fail.

Comment: top_gainer returns `none` check div first

Comment: I think the data you want is generated in javacript which isn't run when you use `requests`. You could use `selenium` instead. It brings up a  browsers to read the page and that runs the javascript.

Comment: added the site source for the data i need

Answer (score 0):

top_gainers_div returns None, because you search `col-md-6`, but in page html class name start with whitespace  `col-md-6`

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense. The problem isn't that the second `.find` returns `None`, the problem is that the first `.find` returns `None` hence the second `.find` is an attribute error since you can't call `find` on `None`.